Clang AST: Unable to detect function call in if statement (CursorKind.UNEXPOSED_EXPR)
I am using Clang's Python bindings (libclang) to analyze a C code file, but I am having trouble detecting a function call within an if statement. Specifically, I expect to detect the function SWI_OS_File_5, but the parsing results in CursorKind.UNEXPOSED_EXPR, and the function call is not detected as I expected.
Here is the problematic C code snippet:
if (SWI_OS_File_5(filename, &type, &load, &exec, (int *)&res->st_size, &attr) != NULL)
    return -1;

Clang AST output:
------Cursor: CursorKind.IF_STMT, ,
--------Cursor: CursorKind.UNEXPOSED_EXPR, ,
----------Spelling:
----------Display Name:
----------Type: _Bool
----------Is Definition: False
----------Reference: None 
--------Cursor: CursorKind.RETURN_STMT, ,
----------Cursor: CursorKind.UNARY_OPERATOR, ,
------------Cursor: CursorKind.INTEGER_LITERAL, ,

python
# Recursively explore AST nodes
def extract_functions(node, the_first, depth=0):
    if the_first:
        the_first = False

    function_list.append('--' * depth + f'Cursor: {node.kind}, {node.spelling}, {node.displayname}')
    
    if node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.UNEXPOSED_EXPR:
        function_list.append('--' * (depth + 1) + f'Node Kind: {node.kind}')
        function_list.append('--' * (depth + 1) + f'Spelling: {node.spelling}')
        function_list.append('--' * (depth + 1) + f'Display Name: {node.displayname}')
        function_list.append('--' * (depth + 1) + f'Type: {node.type.spelling}')
        function_list.append('--' * (depth + 1) + f'Location: {node.location}')
        function_list.append('--' * (depth + 1) + f'Is Definition: {node.is_definition()}')
        function_list.append('--' * (depth + 1) + f'Reference: {node.referenced}')
        
    # Recursively explore child nodes as well
    for child in node.get_children():
        extract_functions(child, the_first, depth + 1)

The issue is that the function call SWI_OS_File_5 inside the if condition is not being detected. Instead, it appears as an UNEXPOSED_EXPR, and there are no child nodes or relevant information in the AST to indicate the function call. I've tried traversing the children of the UNEXPOSED_EXPR node, but to no avail.
Environment:
Clang version: Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1 (system-installed)
Clang build info: Installed in /usr/bin
LLVM version: 20.0.0git (built from source)
LLVM build info: Built with CMake 3.21.2 on 2024-09-24 (latest master branch)
Python bindings: Clang (built from source, using the Python bindings from the source)
Python version: 3.10.12
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
target code:https://github.com/LuaDist/unzip/blob/master/acorn/riscos.c
line 34-35
Question:
How can I correctly detect the function call SWI_OS_File_5 within the if condition? Is there a specific flag or approach needed to expose these expressions correctly in the Clang AST?
I tried using Clang's Python bindings to analyze a C code file. Specifically, I was trying to detect a function call inside an if statement. I expected Clang to correctly identify the function call (SWI_OS_File_5), but instead, I got a CursorKind.UNEXPOSED_EXPR, and the function call was not detected.
Here’s the code snippet I’m analyzing:
# Recursively explore AST nodes
def extract_functions(node, the_first, depth=0):
    if the_first:
        the_first = False

    function_list.append('--' * depth + f'Cursor: {node.kind}, {node.spelling}, {node.displayname}')
    
    if node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.UNEXPOSED_EXPR:
        function_list.append('--' * (depth + 1) + f'Node Kind: {node.kind}')
        function_list.append('--' * (depth + 1) + f'Spelling: {node.spelling}')
        function_list.append('--' * (depth + 1) + f'Display Name: {node.displayname}')
        function_list.append('--' * (depth + 1) + f'Type: {node.type.spelling}')
        function_list.append('--' * (depth + 1) + f'Location: {node.location}')
        function_list.append('--' * (depth + 1) + f'Is Definition: {node.is_definition()}')
        function_list.append('--' * (depth + 1) + f'Reference: {node.referenced}')
        
    # Recursively explore child nodes as well
    for child in node.get_children():
        extract_functions(child, the_first, depth + 1)

What I expected:
I expected Clang to show a CursorKind.CALL_EXPR for the function SWI_OS_File_5.
What actually happened:
Instead, I got a CursorKind.UNEXPOSED_EXPR, with no information about the function call.
------Cursor: CursorKind.IF_STMT, ,
--------Cursor: CursorKind.UNEXPOSED_EXPR, ,
----------Spelling:
----------Display Name:
----------Type: _Bool
----------Is Definition: False
----------Reference: None 
--------Cursor: CursorKind.RETURN_STMT, ,
----------Cursor: CursorKind.UNARY_OPERATOR, ,
------------Cursor: CursorKind.INTEGER_LITERAL, ,


Would you edit the question to add a complete translation unit to parse, rather than just two isolated lines?  That is, add the necessary declarations so the code will parse successfully.  That will make it possible for a reader to reliably reproduce the problem.
